# What do we know to be true before running the java.util.Collections sort(List<T>) function?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, specifications

When we look at the Collections sort method what can we be sure is true before it runs? I know that the list given must be:

- Comparable
- Not null

Are there any other "pre-conditions" for this method that I am missing?

Comment: No, the **list** doesn't have to be Comparable. It helps if the type of objects within the list implement Comparable, but even that's not required. You do know that a sort method overload accepts a Comparator.

Comment: What is your real use-case? This question is only hiding a XY problem.

Comment: @Tunaki: the "real use-case" might simply be that this is a homework question.

Comment: ... or interview question.

Comment: And what do you mean by "pre-conditions"? Not throwing an exception? Code compiling?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Let's assume that the question is about the exact method signature from OP's title. (And yes, I know the 11th commandment is never to assume).

Comment: @Tunaki I am looking into JML so I am defining pre-condition based on JML's definition which would essentially be "what has to be true for this method to run as we would want/expect"

Comment: Look at the documentation. It states the prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) should be your initial entry point:

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. 
>   Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).
>   The specified list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable.

Exceptions:

> Throws:
>   `ClassCastException` - if the list contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers).
>   `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the specified list's list-iterator does not support the set operation.
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - (optional) if the implementation detects that the natural ordering of the list elements is found to violate the Comparable contract